# How to execute a shell script and continue typing?

Tags: shell, expect

I'm trying to execute a shell script that ssh's into a jump server, enter a password and then be able to enter commands or ssh into another server. The issue is that the script ends and I can't enter anymore commands and it exits.

I'm not that proficient in shell scripting, I was hoping someone else had done something similar.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn ssh my@server.com
expect "Password"
send "$1\n"
expect eof
$SHELL
EOD
```

Comment: The obvious method would be to replace `expect eof` with `interact`.  Does that not do what you want?  Check the documentation at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html .

Comment: And also remove `$SHELL` -- that's give you a command-not-found error. ssh drops you into your shell anyway.